# How to place a background-image that fills the entire screen but stops at a certain position from the bottom?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with background image positioning - since we all know, it is quite simple to position a background that repeats itself and STARTS from a certain point from top, what I want to say - let's pretend we want a black background to start 100px from top of page and then repeat-y.

My question is - how is it possible to do the same effect, but the background to repeat-y itself from the bottom, I mean that these 100px of space at the bottom would not be filled with a background.

For now I was lucky enough just to make it so if there is no scrolling, because if there is scrolling, then I see a black background, then 100px at the bottom of window and if I scroll down i see that 100px stripe at the bottom always while scrolling. What I want to make is for background to fill the screen but stop when there is 100px left at the bottom

(at the bottom I want to add a logo which is transparent, so the solution with overflowing one element with another or z-indexing tricks currently is not an option....)

```
body {
    background-image: url(UI/img/stripe-stripe.png)!important;
    background-repeat:  repeat-y !important;
    background-position: right -100px;
    background-color: #e6e2df !important;
}
```

This does not work... I want for a background to repeat vertically but to stop at the bottom when there is 100 px left.

Comment: Your description is very unclear. A drawing would perhaps help but that indicates that this question format is not suited for Stackoverflow. We can help you with specific CSS questions but we can't slice an entire design for you.

Comment: body {
 background-image: url(UI/img/stripe-stripe.png)!important;
 background-repeat:  repeat-y !important;
 background-position: right -100px;
 background-color: #e6e2df !important;
 }

this does not work... i want for a background to repeat vertically but to stop at the bottom when there is 100 px left...

Comment: the best option you have is to make a footer with 100px height and a solid background-color where you display your logo.

Comment: I can't put a solid background here... What I want to do is to have two background images - the one image covers all the area of a window (it is a picture and I have no problems at all with that). The second picture is a "stripe" that fills the screen but it must stop 100 px before the bottom of page so that I am able to put a transparent logo here (now that the second background fills entire window, my transparent logo looks not ok at the right bottom). I just want the background to stop 100 px before the bottom of page. I tried a lot of tricks with css and didn't manage to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just apply the stripe to a div surrounding your content; you could still have a background on the body tag and leave room for a 100px div at the bottom containing your logo:

```
<body>
    <div class="content">
        Content goes here.
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        Logo goes here.
    </div>
</body>
```

And then in your css:

```
div.content {
background-image: url(UI/img/stripe-stripe.png)!important;
background-repeat:  repeat-y !important;
background-position: right -100px;
background-color: #e6e2df !important;
top:0;
bottom:100px;
width:100%;
}

div.footer {
height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: This solution might work but there is one issue that must be then implemented - if there is less content in the .content div, then the footer is not in the bottom of page and the background with a stripe breaks. I use sticky footer so that it sticks to the bottom. If I apply your solution into the content div, then it is fine if there is a lot of content otherwise there happens to be a gap in between and the background is missing because the div do not stretch vertically to the whole window...

Comment: I have updated my answer above, try the new css and see if that fixes your problem. The content div should now always stretch down to the footer regardless of content.

Comment: [JS FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/zhhty/)

it do not work if there is more content than browser window (then this solution breaks). It works only if there is less content than browser window.

Comment: In that case you can add `overflow:scroll;` to the content div. I have updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: It makes the footer to be always visible. I need it to be scrollable also, I mean - the whole page.

Comment: one of the solutions that is kinda worked is using tables http://somacss.com/layouts/stickyfooter_table.html , but it is quite oldschool, I really dont' want that... MAYBE there is some kind of javascript then, that controls the position of background images?

Comment: @Martynas If you want the footer to be scrollable as well making it stick to the bottom of the window is definitely the wrong solution; it sounds like you just want it to be an element below the content tag. I have updated my answer again. Next time try to be more specific in your question or at least update it as you get some feedback, that way you don't have to explain what you want in the comments.